# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value using a script

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

Using the following code I am getting the error:

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "The conversion of a
>   varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range
>   value." At C:\Users\username\Desktop\TEST.ps1:47 char:1
>   + $CommandCompl.fill($dt7) | out-null
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.Size (200, 25)
$Date = (get-date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")


Clear 

$SQLTableCOMPLIA = 'abc'
$SQLServerCOMPLIA = "123.123.123.123"  
$SQLDBNameCOMPLIA = "test"
$UsernameCOMPLIA = "abc"
$PasswordCOMPLIA = "pasword"




$SQLServerLANDESK = "cba\test1"
$SqlConnectionLANDESK = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$global:dt = new-object System.Data.DataTable
$dr = ""

$LONA = ""
$o = 0
$j = 0
$globalvuln , $globalNotvuln = 0


$global:dt7 = new-object System.Data.DataTable

$SqlConnectionCOMPLIA  = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnectionCOMPLIA.ConnectionString = "Server=$SQLServerCOMPLIA;     Database=$SQLDBNameCOMPLIA;uid=$UsernameCOMPLIA; pwd=$PasswordCOMPLIA"

$SqlConnectionCOMPLIA.Open() | out-null

$QueryCompl =  "SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(datetime,left(LD_publishdate,10),103) as R   FROM vulns  order by R DESC" 

$CommandCompl = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ($QueryCompl, $SqlConnectionCOMPLIA) 

$CommandCompl.fill($dt7) | out-null
```

What I am doing wrong? How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm guessing your LD_publishdate column has invalid values, like 31st on a 30-day month or something along those lines. It's basically free text, right?

Comment: @MegaTron Is varchar type and allows Null. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: `select convert(datetime,left('2015-06-31',10),103)` for example gives the error you receive. Null values don't. So i think that's your problem.

Comment: @GeorgeMihailescu Sorry? Why do you think that I ask you anything?

Answer (score 1):

So problem here is simple and problem is with following line

CONVERT(datetime,left(LD_publishdate,10),**103**)

and with style parameter where you mentioned '103' which means you are trying to convert it to British/French standard. For British or french standard your varchar value should be in the format of 'dd/mm/yy' any other format will fail.

For example 
following script will fail with the same error you are getting

select convert(datetime,left('2015/09/21',10),103)

While this will pass swiftly

select convert(datetime,left('21/09/2015',10),103)

Either solve this or try an appropriate value for your style. you can find appropriate values here
http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/convert.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanations. I do not know which rows are not in the correct format in my database. For sure there are, otherwise I would not get the message. I am wondering if there is a way to use an SQL query to return only the rows that are in the "wrong" format so I will know what to fix and how. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Use following script 'select * from <YourTable> where ISDATE (<YourColumn>) = 0' It will give you rows where format of datetime is wrong

Comment: In your case 'select * from vulns where ISDATE(LD_publishdate) = 0'

Comment: The column (LD_publishdate) still shows correct dates. Do you have any idea how to find out why? They are the same format as the "good" ones. Here is an example: GOOD looks like " 12/11/2014 00:00:00" and in general either midnight or fix hours (as in five o clock, or twelve o clock) whereas the values in the same column when using the "=" sign, therefore the "wrong" values are showing  fix hours (as in five o clock, or twelve o clock) AND non fix hours. How can I find what is the difference between those?

Comment: Or maybe a way to make all the wrong values, correct values

Comment: First of all second one is not possible. Can you give me an example of a wrong date that you got from above query.

Comment: If I use SET language British SELECT LD_publishdate FROM [patch_stats].[dbo].[vulns] WHERE ISDATE (LD_publishdate) = 1, then I get LD_publishdate as 24/11/2014 10:29:36, but if I change it to WHERE ISDATE (LD_publishdate) = 0, then I get LD_publishdate as 6/25/2015 12:00:00 AM which is wrong and I want them to either NOT be taken into account either converted to the 24/11/2014 10:29:36 format

Comment: I don't think it can be done automatically George. Sorry. You will have to manually change the dates. Or you can add a check in your original query to not consider ISDATE() = 0 columns

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, it sounds like this part of your SQL query is invalid for the data in the table:  `CONVERT(datetime,left(LD_publishdate,10),103)`.  Try running this query directly without the script and checking the output.

Comment: I am getting "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.
"

Comment: Don't just run that piece.. run the whole query you have specified in $QueryCompl

Comment: "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'LD_publishdate'."

Comment: Sure you're accessing the right database/table?... At least now you should know the problem is elsewhere, and you need to find it... Basically if you can't run the query manually and play with the output, you can't ever expect your script to.